# Adding index to Mysql tables

Tags: mysql, indexing

Which fields should be indexed to speed up the following query?

```
SELECT *
FROM sms_report
WHERE R_uid = '159'
AND R_show = '1'
ORDER BY R_timestamp DESC , R_numbers
```

Comment: now its using filesort, i need to optimize that.

Answer (score 3):

Basing on this information, a composite index on (R_uid, R_show) should be good.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/multiple-column-indexes.html

To be able to tell anything more, you'd need to show us results of EXPLAIN

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain.html

and tell which storage engine is being used.

Comment: id  select_type  table  type  possible_keys  key  key_len  ref  rows  Extra
1  SIMPLE  sms_report  ref  R_uid,R_show  R_uid  4  const  756276  Using where; Using filesort